# PyCharm: Unresolved reference 'com'

Tags: sdk, pycharm, libreoffice, idl, uno

I've been experimenting with PyCharm in conjunction with LO and UNO for some time (win10).

What I don't understand:

Why do I get the error `Unresolved reference 'com'` from PyCharm when I enter the code in editor, but everything seems to be OK, when I run the script with PyCharm or entered in console?

Example:

```
    import uno

    from com.sun.star.awt import Point

    p = Point(100, 200)

    print(p)

    => (com.sun.star.awt.Point){ X = (long)0x64, Y = (long)0xc8 }
```

What I would expect would be a relationship between the UNO interfaces `com.sun.star.awt` and Python so that I can use Intellisense/autocomplete (for example) when entering the code `from com.sun.star.awt import Point` in PyCharm'.

What I know is that all interfaces are described in the IDL files (SDK). I thought it must be possible to define a so-called stub/mock "package" that enables me to do this. Unfortunately, this request is beyond my capabilities at the moment. The attempt to integrate the idl structure from sdk is only inadequate (path structure only).

Are there any ready-made solutions? (which I doubt - intensively searched all sources)

Do I have to live with it now, or which approach would go in the right direction (I love intellisense)? - Maybe I think too complicated?

Comment: My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37193463/5100564 describes the same problem. As mentioned there, I found that UNO intellisense works better for Java; not sure whether that is an option for you.

Comment: @Jim K: yes, stumbled upon your answer in the past and found it very interesting. I just notice that I have to think more fundamentally about the connection between uno and pythen. At the moment i want to give python a chance - java is not an alternative. But thank you anyway :-)